# SQL Delete Multiple Where And Like

Tags: php, sql

This sql code is working wrong. It deletes all values which date 2016-07-27. Could you help me?

```
DELETE FROM price 
WHERE date LIKE '%2016-07-27%' 
    AND (buy,sell NOT LIKE '{$min}' OR NOT LIKE '{$max}')
```

Comment: `AND (buy,sell NOT LIKE` is invalid.

Comment: `AND (WHERE buy,sell NOT LIKE` I tried like this but not fixed. @fred-ii

Comment: so, which one is it you're using? why are you dropping that in comments? that's still  invalid syntax. See the answer below.

Comment: Do you really need wildcards around the `date`? Can't you just use `date != '2016-07-27'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try seperating your buy and sell fields in the query like this:

```
DELETE FROM price 
WHERE date LIKE '%2016-07-27%' 
    AND (buy NOT LIKE '{$min}' AND buy NOT LIKE '{$max}') 
    AND (sell NOT LIKE '{$min}' AND sell NOT LIKE '{$max}')
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, could you try this once more?

Comment: Its working but deleting all values on that date @cagy79

Comment: I changed the OR to AND clauses in the answer. That should do the trick.

Comment: "buy" part is working but "sell" part not working. It keep buy min and max values but delete other things. Not check sell values @cagy79

Answer (score 0):

In sql you can write the code like below.. I dont think we need a like operation over here..

```
DELETE FROM price 
WHERE CAST(date as date) = '2016-07-27' 
          AND buy NOT IN ('{$min}' , '{$max}') 
          AND sell NOT IN ('{$min}' ,'{$max}')
```